# What is the uniqueness of the equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Lee, 'Introduction to Topological Manifolds', Appendix A, Exercise A.2 I am asked to prove that if $\mathcal C$ is a partition of $X$ there is a *unique* equivalence relation $\sim$ such that classes of equivalence of $\sim$ are elements of $\mathcal C$. Since the definition of difference/equality of equivalence relations was not given, I thought that it should be based on the equivalence classes of such a relation.

More formal, am I right stating that

> There is a unique equivalence relation $\sim$ which admits sentence $S$ iff for any $\sim^1$ and $\sim^2$ admitting $S$ their classes of equivalence are the same?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31656/every-equivalence-relation-on-a-set-s-defines-a-corresponding-partition-and-v).

Comment: @ZevChonoles: thank you, I was able to prove this fact - I just wonder what did he mean with the word *unique*. Though, if the relation is a set, then I know have to differ relations. Just would like to know if there is other definition of uniqueness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, an equivalence relation on a set $S$ is a subset of $S\times S$ fulfilling some conditions. This gives you a natural notion of equality for equivalence relations: Two equivalence relations on $S$ are equal if they are given by the same subset of $S\times S$.

It is a general fact that an equivalence relation is uniquely determined by its equivalence classes. This is -- somewhat tautologically -- because two elements are equivalent if and only if they belong to the same equivalence class.

Answer (score 2):

I'd define equality of equivalence relations, or any other relations, as follows.  A relation $\sim_1$ is equal to a relation $\sim_2$ precisely if
$$
\forall a\  \forall b\  (a\sim_1 b \text{ if and only if }a\sim_2 b).
$$

And that would also apply to other relations than equivalence relations.